# Let n be an odd composite number. If $a\not\in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{*},$ is it possible that $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=\pm1$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $n$ is an odd composite number. If $a\notin (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*,$ which means that $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, is it possible that $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}=\pm1?$ If not, how to prove this result?

Thank you so much for any hints and solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, can $a^k$ ($k$ positive integer) and $n$ be coprime?
Also, if the equality were true, would we not be able to say that $a$ is a unit?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I see! If the equality were true, it means that $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\in(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*,$ but this is impossible, since $a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ is also not coprime with $n.$ Thank you so much for this hint!